# Ajax request with nested parameter, getting a 415 error with @requestBody in function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

There is a problem in my app: I will give a nested parameter to background, and it shows the parameter is put in the `TextView` part of the HTTP request. I want to use `@RequestBody` to get the parameter, but once I type the `@RequestBody` annotation in front of the parameter I will get a **415** error~.

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
  url:"maintenance/clientSystem/updatePriceHierarchy.html",
  data: {"post":"515", "person":{"personId":"162"}},
  dataType:"json",
  type:"POST",
  contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function(data){
  console.log("finish");
});
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("client/updatePerson")
  public final void updatePerson(HttpServletResponse response, Person bean) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(bean.getPersonId());
  }
```

**Spring MVC configuration**

```
<!-- for local resources -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>   
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>   
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/deskTopIcon/**" location="/images/deskTopIcon/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/deskTopImg/**" location="/images/deskTopImg/"/>
<!-- scan package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jesse.controller" />

<!-- add annotation driver -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />   
<!-- define prefix and suffix for view -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" /> <property name="suffix"
    value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>

<bean class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" >
   <property name= "messageConverters" >
         <list>
              <ref bean= "stringHttpMessageConverter" />
              <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
              <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
          </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
<bean id = "stringHttpMessageConverter" class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />

<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have added `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` twice and you don't have to specify `supportedMediaTypes` since the message converter will take care of it. In short, remove the `jsonHttpMessageConverter` bean from the context. You also don't have to explicitly declare a `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. It will be registered by default. If you have Jackson on the classpath it will automatically register a converter for it.

Comment: @Bart OK, I will modify my spring-servlet.xml. but I do not think it is the key point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mistakes:

- your controller `updatePerson()` mapping url is `client/updatePerson` and you making AJAX request to `maintenance/clientSystem/updatePriceHierarchy.html`
- your AJAX request is type `POST` and you have not mention what type of method is in controller.
- you have mentioned in question using `@RequestBody`, But i can't see in your controller method.

Correct all those, then coming to:

> getting a 415 error with @RequestBody in function

**HTTP 415** error means **Unsupported Media Type** : The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

**How to get rid 415 error is:**
to specify correct `Content-Type` and `Accept` request headers. Like:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "client/updatePerson",
     data: JSON.stringify(jsonStr),
     async: false,
     cache: false,
     processData:false,
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); //Accept request header specified
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //Content-Type request header specified
     },
     success: function(response){
        alert('Success: '+response.name);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus+' : '+ errorThrown);
     }
});
```

**Note:** `jsonStr` what have specified in AJAX data, that string should be json representation format of a class what you have in controller method, then only spring will convert it back.

for example, your `Person` class will look like:

```
class Person {
    private Long pid;
    private String name;
    private Person person;

    public Person(){} //Default constructor is needed

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then, `jsonStr` will look like:

```
var jsonStr = {"pid": 515, "name": "Jeese"};
```

for nested Persons:

```
var jsonStr = {"pid": 515, "name": "Jeese", "person" : {"pid": 516, "name": "Jeese sub"}};
```

Then, in Controller, method will look like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/client/updatePerson")
public class ClientController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
        public @ResponseBody Person updatePerson(@RequestBody Person bean) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("updatePerson() invoked..");
            //do your works here with person..
            logger.debug(bean.toString());
            logger.debug("Sub person: "+bean.getPerson().toString());
            return bean;
        }
}
```

[jackson-mapper-asl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.11) jar should be available in CLASSPATH.

---

**See also:**

[HTTP Error codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

[**Spring 3.1.X** RequestMapping new features where no need to register `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html)

[RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html?is-external=true)

Comment: solution: Thank you for your answer.
 the URL problem is caused by my default for hidden some detail information of my company, I have found the key point, that is you can not submit parameter that the target form bean do not have, such as **JS**:`{person{name:"jesse",value:"21"},additionalParameter:0}`.if your formBean do not have additionalParameter, you will get a 415 error.
and your answer really helps me much, thanks again.